# Como armazenar um Token JWT em um método simples e redirecionar para uma outra página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
  <button type="button" id="send">enviar</button>
</form>

<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#send').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "URL QUE RETORNA O TOKEN",
      method: "post",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: '{ "email": "your@email.com" }',
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
     }
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

OBS: console.log(data); ME RETORNA O TOKEN PERFEITAMENTE

Comment: Concordo, mas pode ser da maneira mais simples possível(uma variável por exemplo), para fins de teste.

Comment: Você pode sugerir um método que o token não se perca em uma variável?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Armazene o retorno num cookie:

```
localStorage.setItem("token", data);
```

e redirecione:

```
location.href = "pagina.html";
```

Na página redirecionada, recupere o valor armazenado no cookie:

```
localStorage.getItem("token");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, vou realizar os testes.

Comment: Boa sorte! Vai dar certinho.

Comment: Olá, utilizei seu código sugerido, tive a seguinte mensagem de retorno "Content Security Policy: As configurações da página bloquearam o carregamento de um recurso em "1ªURL" (“default-src”)."
O token deve ser enviado pelo método GET para URL /feed, estrutura : curl "URL /feed" \
-H "Authorization: $TOKEN" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
Tentei armazenar o TOKEN em uma var, n consegui por n conhecer a sintaxe e mesmo com exemplos do W3Schools o erro persistiu. Criei uma 2ª função com método POST que use o seu getItem. Chamo a 2ª na 1ªFunction na última linha. Perdão pelos erros.